# Bootstrap 4 basic layout nested container inside container-fluid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using `bootstrap4` to build a basic layout, I have this so far...

```css
.container-fluid {
    background: grey;
}

.container {
    background:wheat;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="container p-5">
      
      <div class="row">
                                
          <div class="col-md-12 pb-5">
      
              <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>      
              <p>This part is inside a .container-fluid class.</p> 
              <p>The .container-fluid class provides a full width container, spanning the entire width of the viewport.</p>

          </div>

      </div>
      
       <div class="row">
                                
          <div class="col-md-6 pb-5">
      
              <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>      
              <p>This part is inside a .container-fluid class.</p> 
              <p>The .container-fluid class provides a full width container, spanning the entire width of the viewport.</p>

          </div>
          
          <div class="col-md-6 pb-5">
      
              <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>      
              <p>This part is inside a .container-fluid class.</p> 
              <p>The .container-fluid class provides a full width container, spanning the entire width of the viewport.</p>

          </div>

      </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

I am using `container-fluid` so that the background is full width, but then nesting `container` inside so that the content within has a maximum width.

Is this a valid way of doing thing? Is there a better way to achieve this kind of layout?

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't applying your `background: grey;` to `html` or `body`?

Comment: Maybe he wants to have different background colors in each section on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you don't nest containers. Each section should only have one container (either `.container` or `.container-fluid`).

If you want the background to be full-width but have maximum width inside, you can just use `<div />` or `<section />` outside of the container. They have their width set to 100% by default:

```html
<section class="bg-secondary">
    <div class="container">
        ...
    </div>
</section>
```

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/0Ljkcmfn/5/